# Best way to add ascii values of a string in c?

Tags: c

I want to add the ascii values of a string, say "hello".
What is the best way to do that in c? is There a way without looping the string?

Comment: If you want to do something using every character in the string, you have to loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can do it without looping:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(const char *s) { return *s == 0 ? 0 : *s + sum(s + 1); }

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sum("hello"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hahah, nice. I don't know if I would call this the _best_ way, though!

Comment: @CoryNelson I agree it's not the best way to do it in C, but it's good to remember about recursion, you know... Looping is boring and it's not the only way to do things ;)

Comment: is == 0 the proper way to check for NULL in c?

Comment: Just out a curiosity,It is faster than an iteration?

Comment: @Jack Probably not, a simple loop will normally be faster.

Comment: @Tom: Yeah. If you compare a to pointer, it same as `(void)*`; to a character `\0`,to an integer just zero-value in octal base(remeber that in C,values beginning with 0 are promoted to be octal)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this without a loop, unless you know the length of the string at compile time.

```
char *str = "hello";
int total = 0;

while(*str) { total += *str++; }
```